# How to define the Quartile range for multivariable and plot the box plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, boxplot

How to plot the Outliers with Box plot for the below data

```
    no,store_id,revenue,profit,state,country
    0,101,779183,281257,WD,India
    1,101,144829,838451,WD,India
    2,101,766465,757565,AL,Japan
```

Code is below, code is there till converting data to `standardscalar` any can choose `minmaxscalar`. After that How to define `Quartile range` to define `outliers`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
df = pd.read_csv(r'anomaly.csv',index_col=False);

df1 = pd.get_dummies(data=df)
df2 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box and whisker plots display the 25th and 75th percentiles of the data by convention.

This is calculated automatically using the medians of the data you provided.

For example, for the following data:

```
no,store_id,revenue,profit,state,country
0,101,779183,281257,WD,India
1,101,144829,838451,WD,India
2,101,766465,757565,AL,Japan
2,101,1000000,757565,AL,Italy
```

You can display the boxplot as follows for the revenue column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
df = pd.read_csv(r'anomaly.csv',index_col=False)

df1 = pd.get_dummies(data=df)
df2 = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df1)

green_diamond = dict(markerfacecolor='g', marker='D')
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Box plot')
ax1.boxplot(df['revenue'], flierprops=green_diamond)
plt.show()
```

The outlier is displayed:

[image: Box plot with outlier]

Comment: how to find the IQR for multivariable by considering all variable not the revenue only